# NSArray subsets and sorting from a dynamic parentArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, core-data, nsarray

I've run into a big question of an approach in order to fuel a graph view.

I retrieve Arrays via coredata.

A Parent Parent <--->>Entry entity relationship exists.

I need to combine the results of parent <-->> Entry relationship into an array sorted by NSDate, thats pretty easy, a parent could have multiple Entries based on timeStamp (NSDate) of adding it.

I use a fetchRequest with the following:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY forParent.entries == %@",selectedTrack]
```

Using that predicate I can take out the entries of Parent of multiple parents into different set of Arrays.

But I would like to have a combined result thats sorted Based on TimeStamps

For example,

```
NSArray Result_ParentA = [entries sortedBy timeStamp]; {A0 ,A1, A2, A3,     A5}   (5)
NSArray Result_ParentB = [entries sortedBy TimeStamp]; {B0, B1, B2, B3, B4}       (5)
NSArray Result_ParentC = [entries sortedBy TimeStamp]; {C0, C1, C2, C3, C4  C5 }  (6)
```

Two points to note here, 
1- Array Result_ParentA  has no entryObject on date "4th" and likewise, B array has no entry on "5th", lets assume those digits to be their NSDates of adding.

I want to have an array that gives me a result as an Array like:

```
CombinedSortedArray objectAtIndex:0] = Array{A0, B0, C0}  CountRemains 3 
CombinedSortedArray objectAtIndex:1] = Array{A1, B1, C1}  Count remains 3
CombinedSortedArray objectAtIndex:4] = Array{0.0, B4, C4}
CombinedSortedArray objectAtIndex:5] = Array{A5, 0.0, C5}
//Count of all the subset Arrays remains 3  which is equal to the count of Parents! Only the difference being that a nil result is replaced by 0.0!
```

2- All this is more complicated by knowing that the Parent is a dynamic number, I can't know how many parents are viewed in the graph..

Perhaps  I should change my fetch request to give me a sorted array  and do some minor changes after I get it..?

Im clueless now, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting a sorted array with your NSSortDescriptor (though you need to set this to be the sort descriptor of the fetch request). All you did by saying NO to the "ascending" parameter is that you'll get them back largest to smallest instead of smallest to largest. Both the NSSortDescriptor and the NSPredicate are optional parameters. If you want all CoreData objects back, just remove the NSPredicate.

Comment: the predicate just retrieves a set of Entries from parents of certain types, its not relevant to the question. I shouldn't have left it there..  I need to parse the array into something like "CombinedSortedArray", and hints on that?